# "FIFO queue full" and "Failed to update header with correct duration" with >1 Mux channel

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ubuntu-20.04

I'm capturing video from Blackmagick Decklink Mini Recorder 4K capture card on Ubuntu 20.04 with ffmpeg 4.3 and I want to send it to several different servers to restream. The video signal is 1080 25p.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 2048 -f decklink -video_input sdi -audio_input embedded -i 'DeckLink Mini Recorder 4K' -threads 4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fps=25,split=2[s720][s360]; \
[s720]scale=-2:720[v720]; \
[s360]scale=-2:360[v360]" \
-map "[v720]" -bufsize:v:0 1600k -maxrate:v:0 1600k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map "[v360]" -bufsize:v:0 1200k -maxrate:v:0 1200k -flvflags no_duration_filesize -flags +global_header \
-map a:0 \
-profile:v:0 main -bf 0 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 96k -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -f tee \
"[select=\'v:0,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://some address|\
[select=\'v:1,a\':f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://some-other-address"
```

I receive the following:

```
[flv @ 0x555f95bf1280] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x555f95bf1280] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[rtmp @ 0x7f58240094c0] Ignoring unsupported var reason1.40 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x
[fifo @ 0x555f95beea80] FIFO queue fullN/A time=00:00:21.88 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x
[fifo @ 0x555f95beea80] Recovery successfultime=00:00:22.92 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x
[fifo @ 0x555f95beea80] FIFO queue flushed
[flv @ 0x555f95bf1280] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x555f95bf1280] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[tee @ 0x555f944a4e80] Slave muxer #1 failed, aborting.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): End of file
[flv @ 0x555f95be9600] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x555f95be9600] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=  581 fps= 25 q=28.0 Lq=28.0 size=N/A time=00:00:23.24 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x
video:4479kB audio:273kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Here is the configure line for the ffmpeg:

```
--prefix=/root/Install/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include -I/root/Install/ffmpeg_sources/BMD_SDK/include' --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-decklink
```

When I run with only one muxer it works fine. The moment I add another it crashes. Have anybody struggled with the same? Any ideas what could be the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is some kind of network problem (or something other, not related to ffmpeg). I was sending both muxer channels to a 3rd party CDN that I have a POC account.

I installed a streaming server on one of our hardware servers at our colocation, I'm sending 5 (different video resolutions and different settings) muxer channels to it and everything works perfect.